# Evaluate $\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{\frac{1}{k}+n}\right)$

Tags: limits, summation, special-functions

Evaluate the limit
$$
\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{\frac{1}{k}+n}\right)
$$

I got stuked when trying to evaluate it and I even don't know where to begin. *Mathematica* tells me that
$$
\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{\frac{1}{k}+n}=\frac{2^{1/n} \left(-\left(2^{1/n}\right)^n \Phi \left(2^{1/n},1,n+1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(2^{1/n}\right)^{n+1} \Phi \left(2^{1/n},1,n+1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-2^{1/n} \Phi \left(2^{1/n},1,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\Phi \left(2^{1/n},1,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+n \left(2^{1/n}\right)^n-n\right)}{\left(2^{1/n}-1\right) n^2}
$$
However it doesn't give the result of the limit either. And I tried $n=10000$ numerically, the answer is $1.44274..$.

So **how to calculate the limit**?

Comment: Are you sure about the last decimals  or could they change slightly with higher n? Because your numeric is pretty close to 1/ln2

Comment: try to use Riemann integral stuff: $\int_0^12^x dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$
\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{\frac{1}{k}+n} = \frac1n\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{\frac{1}{nk}+1}$$ and now
$$\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{\frac{1}{nk}+1}=\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^n 2^{k/n}-\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{nk+1}$$
where the first term converges to $\int_0^1 2 ^xdx$ and the second term vanishes.

Comment: Nice and simple (when you read it !) solution. So, we have as asymptotics $\frac{1}{\log (2)}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{\log (2)}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$ . By the way, $\to +1$ for sure.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is rewarding to have such a nice comment by you! Thank you :-)

Comment: *Three years later !* The sam question came and for the fun of it, I used Euler-MacLaurin summation for a more than marginal improvement. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

*Three years too late*
$$I_n=\int _{1}^n \frac{2^{\frac kn}}{\frac{1}{k}+n}\,dk$$ $$I_n=\frac{2^{-\frac{1}{n^2}}}{n^2}\left(\text{Ei}\left(\frac{(n+1) \log
   (2)}{n^2}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{\left(n^2+1\right) \log
   (2)}{n^2}\right)\right)+\frac{2-2^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\log (2)}$$ is a quite good approximation of the partial sum and, if $n\to \infty$, the result is $\frac{1}{\log (2)}$.

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation, we have
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{\frac kn}}{\frac{1}{k}+n}=\frac{1}{\log (2)}+\frac 1 {2n}-\frac {\log(n)+C}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$  Fot this level of summation
$$C=\text{li}(2)+\frac{32287}{55440}-\gamma -\frac{\log (2)}{12}-\log (\log (2))\sim 1.359$$

For $n=100$, the above truncated series gives $1.4470986$ while the exact summation gives $1.4471001$.

Comment: Nice to look back at things to enjoy again and again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your result $R(n)$ in the last line can be approximated in *Mathematica* using the function

```
Series[R[n],Infinity,1]
```

I got $$\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{\log 2}\to \frac{1}{\log 2}$$